# Remove header conditionnally in active admin on rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to embed my active admin pages in a parent application. 
The active admin page will be shown in an iframe and I need to remove the header and footer on the default index, show and edit pages if the url query param embedded=true.

I proceed like this in my active admin page :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Followup, as: 'Followup_affectation' do

   controller do
     def setLayout
        if  params['embedded'] == 'true'
          @layout = false
        else
          @layout = 'active_admin'
        end
      end
end
```

And in some custom action

```
         render template: "admin/followups/mytemplate.html.haml", layout: @layout
```

But I want to do it for index.

I tried

```
def index
    render :index, layout: @layout
end
```

and

```
def index
   super
   render :index, layout: @layout
end
```

My index definition is really classic :

```
 index do
      id_column
      column :step
      column :cycle
      column :tag_rfid
      column :quoteline
      column :product_name
      column :location
      column :active
      actions
  end
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: could you do something like `before_action :setLayout, only: [:index, :show, :edit]`

Comment: @Richlewis thanks for your help but the issue is on How i remove the layout from the rendering. 
Scope the function does not help in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find a solution. 
1 - Create header.rb in app/admin/

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Header < Component

      def build(namespace, menu)
        super(id: "header")

        #add a class hide wich diplay none on the menu
        if params['embedded'] == 'true'
          super(class: "hide")
        end
        @namespace = namespace
        @menu = menu
        @utility_menu = @namespace.fetch_menu(:utility_navigation)

        build_site_title
        build_global_navigation
        build_utility_navigation
      end


      def build_site_title
        insert_tag view_factory.site_title, @namespace
      end

      def build_global_navigation
        #do not insert tag if params embedded is true
        insert_tag view_factory.global_navigation, @menu, class: 'header-item tabs' unless params['embedded'] == 'true'
      end

      def build_utility_navigation
        insert_tag view_factory.utility_navigation, @utility_menu, id: "utility_nav", class: 'header-item tabs'
      end

    end
  end
end
```